# For loop - Efficient way of print

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, formatting, output

I required some help in correcting the output.

I am suppose to display an output like this: `d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3`

Is there a way to remove the , after the `w:3`?

**Current code**

```py
for i in high:
     print(i[0], ":", i[1], ",", end="")
```

**Current output**

```
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print(','.join(f'{i[0]}:{i[1]}' for i in high))
```

Comment: It printed out 5 times
for i in high:
    print(','.join(f'{i[0]}:{i[1]}' for i in high))
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3

Comment: With this version you don't need to loop over ```high``` anymore. The looping is done in the generator that goes into the ```str.join()``` method.  Just use the given code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for i in range(len(high) - 1):
   item = high[i]
   print(f"{item[0]} : {item[1]},", end="")

item = high[-1]
print(f"{item[0]} : {item[1]}" end="")
```

I know this is not purely a loop, but this the simplest solution.
Also next time you ask a question, please give the value you are working
with.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should solve the problem you are having.

```py
print(','.join(f'{i[0]}:{i[1]}' for i in high]))
```

**Output**

```
d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3
```

It uses the `str.join()` function ([link to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)) alongside a `list` comprehension to essentially print a `list` consisting of a `str` (`f'{i[0]}:{i[1]}'`) `for i in high`, with each `list` element being separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   high = "d:7,s:7,e:6,j:4,w:3,"
   high_split = high.split(',')
   remove_empty_entries = list(filter(None, high_split))

   high_join = ",".join(remove_empty_entries)
   print(high_join)
```